# Не могу собрать akelpad

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, сборка, редактор-текста

Покажите как откомпилировать akelpad.

Мне всего лишь нужно удалить надоедливое оповещение которое мешает при открытии  докумнтов из 7z
Его  легко можно найти:`MSG_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE` типа

```
API_LoadString(hLangModule, MSG_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE, wbuf, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Я пытался скопилировать akelpad
С помошью `code:block` а также Dev C++,
GNU GCC Compiler,
Microsofr visual 2003,
Tiny c compiler.
..

В `code:block` с GNU GCC Compiler я использовал следующие опции: В контекстом меню проекта(версию 4.9.8)

```
Wid32 release english
Target x86
Platform all
Type gui application
```

(Почему то `code:block` по умолчанию установлено на `dll`)
Удалил опцию `-dll` (Ее не понимает компилятор) Если поменять на `-exe`:

```
warning||cannot find entry symbol xe; defaulting to 67f81000|
```

Иногда всплывает *Target is up to date. Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date)*. Тогда приходиться удалять и кидать в папку проект заново.

В итоге вроде бы компиляция выполняеться появляеться файл в 800кб который не открываеться и два файлв `Akelpad.o` `Edit.o` В ином случае выходит dll

Если открыть версию из `vbproj release english win 32` появлеться много undefined reference

Если открыть другие версии выпадает ошибка

```
||=== Build: Library Debug English x64 in AkelPad (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| ld.exe||cannot find -lcmt|
```

Dev C++(Mingv) появляються ошибки тиа

```
3023 C:\1\0note\n\AkelEdit\AkelEdit.c `SETTEXTEX' undeclared (first use in this function),`ST_SELECTION' undeclared (first use in this function)
`ST_KEEPUNDO' undeclared (first use in this function),structure has no member named `lpUsedDefChar',
```

Из-за урезанной сборки Ос я не могу установить net framework и microsoft sdk.

Я не програмист.
Прошу скажите как скомпилировать akelpad без microsoft sdk используя любой другой компилятор.

Comment: Открыл проект в 2017 студии, не собирается. Нашел файл `AkelFiles/Langs/Resources/Version.rc`, удалил секцию с манифестом (c 6 по 12 строку). 

Потом в свойствах проекта C++->CodeGeneration->Basic runtime check выставил в default.

Comment: Поправил форматирование немного. Проверьте, что всё в порядке по смыслу.